# PHP Session Lost on Console Command

Tags: php, session, cookies

I know the session has not worked on console command, I have an application which has 3 steps or pages:

Step1 Page: I have started the session and have session id say "XYZ".

Step2 Page: I have Run some script or PHP code in the background or in the console and send output to the browser, and on this step2 try to get the session id but it have no value. and I am redirecting  to step 3

Step3 Page: When I try to get the value of session id then I can get session id "XYZ".

Now please let me know how can I get session id value in step 2.

Or there is any other way where I can hold any unique value and I will be work for each client machine(User) like session. I try cache but it will not for each user or client.

Thanks.

Comment: you could just send the session values to the command line sctipt.

Comment: If you have started a session in one page , to  access session variable in others page you have to put **session_start()** in each of them at the beginning of the page

Answer (score 0):

console(cli) scripts dont have access to session vars as there not http header to send a session id.

I dont know how exactly your running background php but you can parse the variables to it like so

`exec("php sctipt.php  $_SESSION['v1'] $_SESSION['v2']")`

in the script, the variables wit h be in the `$argv` array

ref: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php